# Array Destructuring with in a for of loop?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to understand the following code? and why i get the following output

```js
for (let [i, j, ...x] of [
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13].filter(e => e > 5)
  ]) {
  console.error(x)
}
```

expected output `[10, 11, 12, 13]`
 actual output `x = [12, 13]`

Comment: `i` is 10, `j` is 11, `x` holds the rest, hence `[12,13]`.

Comment: just run snippet of my answer.

Comment: The for..of loop in that case is using multiple iteration variables. Because of that it will take many elements from the array. in the first loop, first element of the array will be assigned to i, second to j and all the others to x. The loop will end here, cause " ...x " has already taken all of the remaining elements and there is nothing left. And of course, using filter on the initial array will leave you with only four elements [10, 11, 12, 13]. So: x is 10, j is 11, x is [12, 13].

Edit: Played a bit with the code. There will always be only one iteration, even without " ...x " var.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(let [i, j, ...x] of [[2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13].filter(e => e > 5 )]) {
  console.error(x)
}
```

First you need to look at `[2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13].filter(e => e > 5 )`
which returns: `[10, 11, 12, 13]`.

Afterwards `[i, j, ...x] = [10, 11, 12, 13]`will get applied. This means, `i = 10`, `j = 11` and x takes the rest which means `x = [12, 13]`.

We print `x` and voila, it's `[12, 13]`.

---

But what about `[[10, 11, 12, 13]]`? First see the snippet below:

```js
let [k, l, ...y] = [2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13]

console.log(k,l,y)

let [i, j, ...x] = [[2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13]]

console.log(i,j,x)
```

So with a single bracket we get the expected results so why in the given code we have double brackets and it works just fine?

Well, see the following snippet and compare:

```js
for (let [i, j, ...x] of [[2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13]]) {
  console.log(i,j,x)
}
```

This works just fine but what happens when we loop with single brackets?

```js
for (let [i, j, ...x] of [2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13]) {
  console.log(i,j,x)
}
```

We get an error! But why?

`for...of` gets us the inner values of the array of array via its internal iterator. It gets us the 'next' element from our outer array which is our inner array. That's why we only ever got a single iteration in our loop anyway since there is only one 'next'!

On that single element we are iterating we apply the deconstructing syntax and print the result. It's a lot of hot air over nothing, basically.

Comment: @briosheje, I added an explanation for it!

Comment: _Afterwards [i, j, ...x] of [10, 11, 12, 13]will get applied._ I would change to: `[i,j,...x] = [10,11,12,13]`. The "of" is misleading, since `of` in that context expects an iterator, which is found, of course, but would raise an exception. It's an assignment, using for..of against [10,11,12,13] would raise a TypeError :). Good job adding further explanations anyway, this is the kind of quality answers needed.

Comment: Changed it, thank you for the hint and the kind words!

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to remove `i,j`

```js
for (let [...x] of [
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13].filter(e => e > 5)
  ]) {
  console.error(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get numbers that are larger than 5 , you can use this code

```
for (let [i, j, ...x] of [
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13].filter(e => e > 5)
  ]) {
  console.error(x)
}
var numberArray=  [2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13];
var numberBiggerThanFive = [];
for(i in numberArray){
 if(i > 5 ){
   numberBiggerThanFive.push(i)
   }
 }
console.log(numberBiggerThanFive);
```